# Any idea why geth --fast is taking so much CPU *AFTER* sync is done

Tags: go-ethereum

I'm running geth 1.4.17-stable. Also running Mist 0.8.6. While geth finished fast syncing up a few hours ago, it's still eating away at my laptop's CPU. Note I'm not trying to mine.

Is that normal for geth or is there anything I can do to reduce its CPU usage?

[image: top]

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

After Syncing, geth is trying to mine (calculating hashes to get a succesfull block and its reward).
Mining requires lot of computation power due to the HASH calculation.

That's the reason.

Comment: I'm not trying to mine. I thought geth mines only if I pass the --mine flag, is that not right?

Comment: Or by sending miner.start console command.
Are you sure geth is not trying to mine?
What net are you connected to?

Comment: Thanks, I don't know that I sent a minder.start command. I believe I'm connected to the main (prod) network, as I'm able to see balances etc.
In general, I just ran geth --fast first time, or geth in subsequent times, so all the default options should have kicked in I guess...?

Comment: Probably that's the reason.
You can try this command: `geth --fast console`
It gives you a console commands, then after syncing ensure you are not mining by using `miner.stop`.
But if you are "playing" on the main net, then the syncing will keep forever (as new blocks are being mined by other nodes).

Comment: I understand syncing goes on and that's fine, I just hoped syncing doesn't eat so many resources.
Actually, now for some reason it calmed down, eating only 5%ish CPU. Thanks @KanekiDev!